# What is the origin of スタンド meaning "desk lamp"?

Tags: etymology

I'm struggling to turn up any answers on why the word スタンド is used to mean "desk lamp". My guess would be that it's a case of metonymy, but I don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's short for 電気【でんき】スタンド, which we can see in [sense ② in Daijirin](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89):

> ②「電気スタンド」の略【りゃく】。

Here, 略 means "abbreviation".  And of course, 電気{でんき} means both "electricity" and "[electric] light".  Why does 電気 have this meaning?  Well, most dictionaries don't say, and I suppose *this* could be simple metonymy, but when we look up 電気 in 日本国語大辞典, we find:

> ③（「⇨でんきとう（電気灯）の略）電灯{でんとう}。

So we could consider スタンド as indirectly short for 電気{でんき} "electric" 灯{とう} "light" スタンド "stand".